# Unity Change Rotation of Animated Object at Runtime

Tags: unity, animation, rotation

[image]

So I made an animation, but sometimes i nedd to rotate the animation, but for some reason it isnt working. I can change the rotation of the object and then click play and it works perfectly like in the gif, but if I attempt to change the rotation on runtime nothing happens. Why?

Comment: You can change the rotation in the animation itself if that's what you want to achieve. This is an older version link but it should apply for current version for animation editor too: https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/animeditor-AnimationCurves.html

Comment: the problem is that the rotation is dependent on an action that happens while playing. It doesnt help to set the rotation to one fixed value

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because the actual rotation is encoded into the animation itself, overriding your changes. You can try to make the animated object a child of an empty one and rotate the parent instead. This way your should get the expected result.

Comment: i tried that, but it didnt work, i could change the rotation of the parent, but the child didnt roatae

Comment: @Zarazas impossible. Either you did not do it correctly or something else is wrong.